# Python property setter/getter reference

Tags: python

I have a class where I have to give back a callback function in the **iter** function.
With attributes and get_... style it is easy:

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.attrib = 'bla'

    def get_attrib(self):
        return self.attrib

    def __iter__(self):
        yield ('attrib',self.get_attrib)

    def __str__(self):
        ret = ''
        for one in self:
            ret += '%s: %s\n'%(one[0],one[1]())
        return ret

print(Test())
```

I would like to be more pythonic and use properties. But how can I do the same with the getter of the propertyr? Because this does not work:

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._prop = 'bla'

    @property
    def prop(self):
        return self._prop

    def __iter__(self):
        yield ('prop',self.prop.__get__)

    def __str__(self):
        ret = ''
        for one in self:
            ret += '%s: %s\n'%(one[0],one[1]())
        return ret

print(Test())
```

I found the following but it requires the object itself as an argument when I call it:

```
def __iter__(self):
        yield ('prop',self.__class__.prop.__get__)

a = Test()
for one in a:
    print '%s: %s'%(one[0],one[1](a)
```

**UPDATE**: I need the setter as well but I wanted to make the example simple enough. So at the end I would like to have something like:

```
def __iter__(self):
            yield ('prop',self.prop.__get__,self.prop.__set__)
```

Comment: Why are you making `iter()` iterate over properties of your class? Is that really useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a lambda:

```
    yield ('prop',lambda: self.prop)
```

Comment: Hmm.. sems to be a good idea. But what can I do with the setter? (I need that one as well but wanted to make the example simple)

Comment: Thanks. So the final solution is: yield ('prop',lambda: self.__class__.prop.__get__(self),lambda x: self.__class__.prop.__set__(self,x))

Answer (score 1):

If you want the getter and setter to be callable and accessible as a property, you can do the following

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._prop = 'bla'

    def get_prop(self):
        return self._prop

    def set_prop(self, val):
        self._prop = val

    prop = property(get_prop, set_prop)

    def __iter__(self):
        yield ('prop',self.get_prop, self.set_prop)
```

You can now use

```
test = Test()
test.prop = 'foo'
print(test.prop)

for a in prop:
    name, getter, setter = a
```

Comment: That is the point. I would like to get the function that I can call and not the value of the property.

Comment: When why do you want to use a property?

Comment: Well, my understanding is that using get_attrib and set_attrib is not pythonic way of setting attributes. But I need to do other things as well when I set some attribute. That is why the property is needed in my case. Unfortunately it seems with properties I run into a different wall. So, I may fall back to the set_ and get_ solution.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `self.prop` and remove the `()` call from the iteration. Here `self.prop` will return the string(`'bla'`) itself and you're trying to call `__get__` on that string, which results in an error as strings don't have any `__get__` attribute.:

```
def __iter__(self):
    yield ('prop', self.prop)

def __str__(self):
    ret = ''
    for one in self:
        ret += '%s: %s\n' % (one[0],one[1]) #remove () call from here
```

Here `self.prop` is equivalent to:

```
Test.prop.__get__(a)
```

**Update:** Don't use `@property` if you want to call it as a function:

```
def prop(self):
    return self._prop

def __iter__(self):
    yield ('prop', self.prop)
```

Comment: That is the point. I would like to get the function that I can call and not the value of the property.

Comment: @BalazsZachar Then define it as a simple method, what's the point of using a property then?

Comment: The problem is that I will need the setter as well. Additionally, I do not feel this a better solution then the get_attrib that I wrote before.